# How to access specific value of an array from json file using shellscript

Tags: arrays, json, shell, parsing, key-value

I have the following Json file.

```
{
  "pagelen": 50,
  "values": [
    {
      "rm": "dev",
      "links": {
        "watchers": {
          "gre": "hello_world"
        },
        "url": [
          {
            "href": "test.com",
            "name": "http"
          },
          {
            "href": "ignore",
            "name": "ssh"
          }
        ],
    }
    "page": 1,
    "size": 10
}
```

I want to pass every `url` value to an for loop.

As I am now to shell scripting, I couldn't find the better way to do it.

every `url` value should be passed in the loop

how we can achieve this?

Comment: may help this json parse https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools

Comment: Look into `jq`, it is built for JSON parsing.  Scripts for that become big and bug prone quickly.  That being said, in your particular situation, `grep` and `cut` will do the trick nicely, since you want all of the href values anyway.